# Set data from $.post into a var

Tags: jquery, ajax

The code:

```
 $.post('script.php',{value:value},function(data)
 {
        var Aquaman= ???;
 });
```

Now my question is if I want to set the data value into the Aquaman variable, how do I do it?

Comment: @Rune, I tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: The answer from @RuneFS is perfectly valid but yet ... it might not work for you as expected, because of the answer from Blazemonger

Comment: What you are currently doing is how you are supposed to do it. Just keep in mind, it's only available inside the `function(){}` that you pass into `$.post`

Comment: ... or (if it is a global variable) it will also be available outside of the callback. But only after(!) the request finished. You'll have to get rid of the "var" keyword then!

Comment: @devnull69 Sure, if you want to use a setTimeout or some other event to deal with an ajax request that may take 10 ms or 45 seconds, or switch to *gasp* `async:false`

Comment: Note: it's not good practice to name your variable `Aquaman`, with the uppercase `A`. Leave uppercased initials for constructor functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of asynchronous logic.

All you need to do is `var Aquaman = data;` -- however, that variable will ONLY exist inside that anonymous function.

You can get around this by assign global variables in the usual manner:

```
 var Aquaman;
 $.post('script.php',{value:value},function(data) {
      Aquaman= data;
 });
```

However, this global variable won't be set until after your AJAX call is completed. This may be desirable if, for instance, `Aquaman` is being called by other AJAX calls or user events. However, the following code won't work as you might expect:

```
 var Aquaman;
 $.post('script.php',{value:value},function(data) {
      Aquaman= data;
 });
 console.log(Aquaman); // displays nothing
```

...because `console.log()` is run immediately and before the `$.post()` is completed.

The only way to prevent *that* is to make a synchronous [AJAX call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({url: 'script.php', data: {value:value}, async: false}, function(data) {...});
```

...but this nullifies most of the advantages of AJAX by forcing your script to stop and wait for the callback to complete. In almost all cases, it's better to let your AJAX remain asynchronous and deal with the `data` inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the value of `data` to `Aquaman` is as easy as the following:

```
$.post('script.php',{value:value},function(data){
    var Aquaman= data;
});
```

However, because of [variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope) if you need this value outside of the `$.post` callback you need to define `Aquaman` outside of this function. For example:

```
//Some Code
$.post(...,function(data){
  var Aquaman = data;
});

// Aquaman is undefined out here.
```

However:

```
var Aquaman;
$.post(...,function(data){
    Aquaman = data;
});
// Aquaman exists (but be careful, AJAX calls make this value not accessible
// until the callback has been executed.)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple to a so basic question, declare your Aquaman variable in global scope:

```
var Aquaman;

function something()
{
     $.post('script.php',{value:value},function(data)
     {
         Aquaman= data;
     });
}
```

You can find better way to do this, see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915794/calling-variable-from-another-function-in-javascript/12916127#12916127).